# iCal feeds do not pass ical validation?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a .ics file which I am trying to validate from the site http://severinghaus.org/projects/icv/

Actually it's giving the following error:

Sorry, your calendar could not be parsed.
Error:  Error was: Error at line 13: Illegal component [ALARM]
Cause:  Caused by: Illegal component [ALARM]

10: UID:1351
11: LOCATION: asdfghasdfgasdg, 27514
12: CLASS:PUBLIC
13: BEGIN:ALARM
14: TRIGGER:
15: ACTION:
16: DESCRIPTION:

Can somebody help me with this one.

Thanks

Comment: past a couple of lines from the file from 10 to 20 or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try changing ALARM to VALARM?

For instance, this validates:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//ABC Corporation//NONSGML My Product//EN
BEGIN:VTODO
DTSTAMP:19980130T134500Z
SEQUENCE:2
UID:uid4@host1.com
ORGANIZER:MAILTO:unclesam@us.gov
ATTENDEE;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED:MAILTO:jqpublic@example.com
DUE:19980415T235959
STATUS:NEEDS-ACTION
SUMMARY:Submit Income Taxes
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:AUDIO
TRIGGER:19980403T120000
ATTACH;FMTTYPE=audio/basic:http://example.com/pub/audio-
 files/ssbanner.aud
REPEAT:4
DURATION:PT1H
END:VALARM
END:VTODO
END:VCALENDAR
```

This does not:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//ABC Corporation//NONSGML My Product//EN
BEGIN:VTODO
DTSTAMP:19980130T134500Z
SEQUENCE:2
UID:uid4@host1.com
ORGANIZER:MAILTO:unclesam@us.gov
ATTENDEE;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED:MAILTO:jqpublic@example.com
DUE:19980415T235959
STATUS:NEEDS-ACTION
SUMMARY:Submit Income Taxes
BEGIN:ALARM
ACTION:AUDIO
TRIGGER:19980403T120000
ATTACH;FMTTYPE=audio/basic:http://example.com/pub/audio-
 files/ssbanner.aud
REPEAT:4
DURATION:PT1H
END:ALARM
END:VTODO
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: Hi,I have changed it to 'VALARM' as you mentioned and it's validated, but now when I download the .ics file and add it to the calendar it gives me the following error.cannot import vcalendar file. Could not complete the operation. One or more parameter values are not valid